# Benthic Golden Oracle: Return multiple ref cursors from procedure for viewing

Tags: cursor, procedure

I'm used to running a procedure and returning one cursor for viewing:

```
var recCursos refcursor;
exec user.package.procedure(inputValue1, :recCursor);
```

However, this time I need to run a procedure that has 5 outbound cursors and want to be able to view them all.  What is the easiest way to do this?  So far I've only found online articles about doing it programmatically, not within Benthic Golden (or other SQL UI).

Answer (score 2):

Golden has a predefined variable for displaying a single cursor ":cursor"

```
exec user.package.procedure(inputValue1, :cursor);
```

I don't see the 5 cursor sample, but depending on which version of Golden you are using, there  may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

[Golden](http://www.benthicsoftware.com/golden6.html) handles the standard Oracle script syntax, so you can just use:

```
var cursor1 refcursor;
var cursor2 refcursor;
exec MyMultiCursorProc(inputValue1, :cursor1, :cursor2);
print cursor1;
print cursor2;
```

You can also show each defined cursor by choosing the "show cursor [cursor name]" menu item that is on the Results | Bind variable cursors menu.